# Getting a list of everyone that likes a link.

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

If I create a page, is it possible to get a list of all the people that like that page on facebook. For example, if I create http://www.facebook.com/honeybadger, as an admin can I get a list of everyone that likes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get a list of users who like a URL or Facebook page anymore. Facebook has gone and taken the `page_fan` and `url_like` tables and made the only indexable column on these the `uid` field.

Trying something like this

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page WHERE username = "honeybadger")
```

Throws an OAuth exception: "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql"

The only thing you can do is create an app, have users authorize your app, then test if an authenticated user likes a specific page or link. If you ask for the right permissions, you can also test to see if their friends like your app.

This change was implemented to prevent spammers from harvesting Facebook IDs from their page fans or url likers.

Comment: Gotcha that seems to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook documentation seems to give the exact answer to your question.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id = <INSERT_FACEBOOK_OBJECT_ID_HERE>
```

Answer (score 0):

simpler way is to get it thru graph api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/honeybadger/likes?access_token=valid_access_token
```